# How can I join two tables and fetch rows from the resultant table

Tags: sql, mysql, flask

I have two tables and I want to fetch rows by joining these two table in MySQLdb(flask).
Table 1: `products`
Table 2: `links`

products:

```
pid  name  price
101  p1    45
102  p2    55
103  p3    65
```

links:

```
pid buy_link img_link
101  buy/xyz  img/xyz
102  buy/abc  img/abc
103  buy/jkl  img/jkl
```

after join(`final_table`):

```
pid  name  price  img_link
101  p1    45     img/xyz 
102  p2    55     img/abc
103  p3    65     img/jkl
```

to join tables:

```
SELECT products.pid, products.name, products.price, links.img_link FROM products LEFT JOIN links ON products.pid=links.pid;
```

how can I fetch rows from it? like,
`select pid, name, img_link from final_table where price > 50;`

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you ask about flask orm? If so:

    ProductsModel.query.join(LinksModel, ProductsModel.pid == LinksModel.pid).filter(ProductsModel.price > 50).all(), sql code is almost like you wrote.